# Bootstrap col-md-12, col-sm-12 doesn't work with bootstraps selectpicker

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-selectpicker

I need to use bootstrap selectpicker, it looks good if I have large screen, but if I reduce the screen size my selects layered, but I want to show them separately.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nastya2410/4o2umka6/5/

For show the `select` I use:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <select class="selectpicker show-tick">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

How can I solve my problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You apply your width to a div not to your selector You have several solution :

- Apply `col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12` on your selector
- Add this css property to your selector : `select{width:inherit;}`

Answer (score 0):

Your quickest way is to remove this absolute positioning style:

```
.bootstrap-select:not([class*="col-"]):not([class*="form-control"]):not(.input-group-btn) {
    width:180px;
    left: 0;
    /* position: absolute; */ /* This is being removed */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="selectpicker show-tick col-xs-12">
```

use responsive class in the select tag it works